# Prepared Statement only retrieves the first row

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm developing a web application in which users can insert a number of "products". These products will be inserted in a MySQL database. I have a problem when I try to retrieve data from a table of my database. Here is my method:

```
public ArrayList<Product> getProductByAppId(int appId) {
        ArrayList<Product> list = new ArrayList<Product>();
        String query = "select prodId from app_prod where appId = ?";

        try {
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, appId);
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                Product item = getProductById(resultSet.getInt("prodId"));
                list.add(item);
            } 
            return list;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
}
```

This method simply gets an int as a parameter and retrieves from the table `app_prod` all the objects I have stored. The method `getProductById` it's an helper method and it works properly. When I try to debug my code, I see that I enter in the while cycle only once! So all I see is the very first element in my DB, but I have more than a single product in my DB.

To make things shorter, I've omitted methods to open and close connection because they work properly.

I think the error is something very obvious, but I can't really see it.

Comment: Probably you're reusing the same connection for both methods and you're closing the connection in `getProductById`.

Comment: What is the code of `getProductById` ?

Comment: Why aren’t `preparedStatement` and `resultSet` local variables? At least `resultSet` *should* be a local variable as it has no meaning outside the method and should be closed afterwards. I bet you are overwriting `resultSet` within `getProductById`…

Comment: You are sure that you have more than one  `prodId` with `appid=1`. Can you try this `int size= 0;
if (rs != null)   
{  
  rs.beforeFirst();  
  rs.last();  
  size = rs.getRow();  
}  ` to find out how many rows you have in your resultset?

Comment: @dylaniato How many rows you get when you run `select prodId from app_prod where appId = ?` query in backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK the problem is the following:

`resultSet` is declared as a global variable and is being used by both methods.
When the second method changes its contents and gets through it by :

```
resultSet.next();
```

And reaches the end of it:

The main outer loop tries to do `resultSet.next()`, it directly exits from the loop since it had already reached its end beforehand in the `getProductById` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<Product> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, appId);
        try (resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                Product item = getProductById(resultSet.getInt("prodId"));
                list.add(item);
            } 
            return list;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The try-with-resources ensure that statement and resultset are closed (even despite the return).

Also now the variables are local. And *that* might be the problem: maybe you reused those global fields in `getProductById`. `resultSet` would be my guess. (Pardon me.)